# Linq to SQL Like search with a "#" sign

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq

Have a linq to sql "Like" query (VB.Net) which is using this as a comparison value:

%HIPP,%JOHN%A%LLLP%#1%

Here is the query:

docs.Where(Function(d) d.Parties.Where(Function(p) p.PartyName Like partyName And p.PartyName <> "" And p.PartyType = 2).Any)

partyName = %HIPP,%JOHN%A%LLLP%#1%

However when profiling the query in SQL Server the "#" is coming across as [0-9], so the sql statement says "... where field like %HIPP,%JOHN%A%LLLP%[0-9]1% so it is obviously not returning the values I am looking for.

Can anyone shed some light on what is going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: I added the linq query to my original question.

Comment: You can use linqpad to duplicate this, just use an "#" in a linq Like query and you will see that the sql it generates replaces the "#" sign with the text [0-9].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx):

> To match the special characters left bracket ([), question mark (?), number sign (#), and asterisk (*), enclose them in brackets.

So your search term should be

```
HIPP,*JOHN*A*LLLP*[#]1*
```

Note that you also should use `*` in stead of `%`.

Also note that you can use...

```
p.PartyName.Contains(partyName)
```

...which translates to `LIKE`. It encloses `partyName` in `%` characters and escapes wildcard characters: `Contains("a%")` is translated as `LIKE '%a~%%' ESCAPE '~'`.

Or...

```
SqlMethods.Like(p.PartyName, partyName)
```

...which uses `partyName` as-is, and handles wildcard characters as usual for `LIKE` (SQL).

Comment: "To match the special characters left bracket ([), question mark (?), number sign (#), and asterisk (*), enclose them in brackets."

That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you! 

I am using "*" as a wildcard character, what I pasted was the result in the sql profiler. I'll try enclosing the "#" in brackets and see what happens. Doing a "Contains" search does not replace the "#", but it also does not work with the string I am trying to compare to.

I'll post a comment once I give it a shot, thank you!

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. I knew it had to be something like that but could not find anything through google, thanks for finding that MSDN documentation!